# When created a project with IntelliJ plugin TornadoFx the build fails

Tags: tornadofx

Installed the IntelliJ plugin for TornadoFx and then restarted the IDE. 
Got a message: The build is failed.

Answer (score 1):

1. On the right side of the IDE there is a "grade" menu tab, select it.
2. In the opened side window choose the "Gradle settings" icon (the right one).
3. At the bottom, under the Gradle title, you will see a spinner with the title "Use Gradle from", select "'gradle-wrapper.properites' file"

That's it.